# NativeScript Playground: moment.js npm package included but error requiring moment

Tags: momentjs, nativescript, require

I just started experimenting with Nativescript and am using the Playground to test things and see how it works.
What I wanted to do: add the moment.js module for formatting date/time
What I tried:
 1. added the moment package. This appears to have worked because Playground now shows the moment folder along with files (package.json, ender.js, moment.js, etc) and subfolders.
 2. In my code I used this snippet to require "moment"

```
var Moment = require("moment");
```

This failed though because I get an error of

```
Error: Could not find module 'moment'. Computed path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxx/Documents/Playground/LiveSync/app/tns_modules/moment'
```

Any suggestions on what I need to change to get it to find 'moment'? I checked in package.json and it has the name as "moment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default require statement will search for the module form the `tns_modules` directory that was packed with the app during build time. So with Playground you could use relative path.

For example, if you want to use it on `app.js` which is in the root level,

```
var Moment = require('./moment');
```